# “Bauer” vs. “Landwirt”

Tags: meaning, difference

It seems that both, *Bauer* and *Landwirt* mean *farmer. Landwirt,* I guess, is someone who does *Landwirtschaft. Bauer,* apparently, has some additional meanings, including *pawn (chess piece).*

Is there any fine difference between these two when we are talking about farmers? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Landwirt** is a modern higher word. It implies managing and maintaining a farm as a whole economic structure like a company. You will find it rather in professional job descriptions and "official" written language.

**Bauer** is an ancient term which is more broad and sometimes also used as swearword. However there are many farmers who are proud for being explicit a "simple" Bauer since they see it from a traditional way. Nowadays a Bauer has many obligations because of rules and economic pressure.

Conclusion: Both words are still in use, it little depends from context if your opposite sees Bauer with negative implications. To be sure and if you want to sound professional I recommend to use Landwirt.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "a modern higher word". "Landwirt" and "Landwirtshaft" are attested in their modern meaning since the 18th century. See: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Landwirt

Comment: @fdb: Thanks for the link. "modern" in language history is really hard to judge, however in relation to Bauer it is really new. Do you have an alternative to express this?